# Accessing QGIS 3D library with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, 3d

I just found the new 3D map feature in QGIS 3, and information about the API in C++ [here](https://qgis.org/api/group__d.html).

I would like to access to the API using Python, for example to change camera view point and save 3D view to image file. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked through the [Python API docs](http://python.qgis.org/api/index.html)? There are a number of items there which reference the 3D renderer, but I can't say for certain that they're what you want, as I haven't used them.

Comment: Yes, I first have a look to this doc, but there is nothing about the new 3D library (Qgs3DMapScene, Qgs3DMapSettings, ...)

Comment: it seems that Qgs3DMapSettings is accessible in Python : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/3d/auto_generated/qgs3dmapsettings.sip.in (but I didn't find Qgs3DMapScene)

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.28, this is not possible. The 3D code needs restructuring so that it can be used like other parts of the QGIS libraries.

See https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2022-November/065258.html and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2022-November/065261.html for some context.